# Como passar variável por parâmetro criada no enum em Java?

Tags: java

Criei uma Classe `enum` do `java`

```
public enum Cor {
    AZUL(1),VERMELHO(2),VERDE(3);
    private int var;
     Cor(int var)
    {
    this.var = var;
    }
}
```

No `main` vou criar um menu usando `do/while` e `switch/case`
e será mostrado as as cores, como pegar a cor escolhida e passar no parâmetro de um método?

No menu vai tá assim

```
                System.err.println("Escolha uma cor");
                System.err.println("1-Azul");
                System.err.println("2-Vermelho");
                System.err.println("3-Verde");
```

Ao usuário digitar 1 deve pegar a cor Azul.

Comment: Você quer o valor do `var`? Exemplo: `Cor minhaCor = Cor.AZUL;` e então `int valorCor = minhaCor.val`, algo assim que você quer? Se sim, basta criar um getter dentro da Enum: `public int getVar() { return this.var; } .... minhaCor.getVar()`

Comment: @AlfredBaudisch de uma olhada na edição

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos há dois exemplos:

**Switch**
Para utilizar o `switch` é necessário criar Constantes com os respectivos valores:

```
public static final int AZUL= 1;
public static final int VERMELHO= 2;
public static final int VERDE= 3;

public static Cor selecaoPorSwitch(int selecao){
    Cor cor= null;
    switch (selecao) {
    case AZUL:
        cor = Cor.AZUL;
        break;
    case VERMELHO:
        cor = Cor.VERMELHO;
        break;
    case VERDE:
        cor = Cor.VERDE;
        break;
    }
     return cor;
}
```

**if / else**

Comparação simples do valor com a seleção. 
Para isto é necessário criar o `getVar()` para termos acesso ao valor de cada `enum`:

```
public static Cor selecaoPorIf(int selecao){
    Cor cor = null;
    if(selecao == Cor.AZUL.getVar()){
        cor = Cor.AZUL;
    }else if(selecao == Cor.VERDE.getVar()){
        cor = Cor.VERDE;
    }else if(selecao == Cor.VERMELHO.getVar()){
        cor = Cor.VERMELHO;
    }
    return cor;
}
```

Como testar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Selecione uma cor: \n 1-Azul\n2-Vermelho\n3-verde \n :");
    int selecao = scan.nextInt();
    Cor cor = selecaoPorIf(selecao);
    System.out.println("selecaoPorIf : "+cor);

    cor = selecaoPorSwitch(selecao);
    System.out.println("selecaoPorSwitch : "+cor);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo o que eu entendi você gostaria de fazer um menu do tipo:

1. AZUL
2. VERMELHO
3. VERDE

Caso seja isso você pode fazer o seguinte. 
Para apresentar o menu:

`for(Cor cor : Cor.values()) {
     System.out.println(cor.getIndice() + ". " + cor.name());
 }`

Para selecionar a cor, o usuario pode entrar um indice. Dessa forma você pode adicionar o seguinte método no enum:

```
public static Cor fromIndice(int indice){
    for(Cor cor : Cor.values()) {
        System.out.println(cor.getIndice() + "-" + cor.name());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Indice invalido");
}
```

Que ao receber um indice retorna uma cor.

Caso não seja isso, adicione mais informações.